# SoapUI Xpath assertion: match the exact length of the field

Tags: xpath, soapui

I need to match, exact length of a string and I'm using below code for that :

```
declare namespace 
ns123='urn:lt:sb:xmlns:services:customers:customerinformationfile:GetCustByGlobalId:1.2';
matches(//ns123:legalCode, "[0-9-]{10}")
```

Problem is that it works only for greater length (for example, if field content is 11, it fails, but it doesn't, if the content is 9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^[0-9-]{10}$
```

instead of your `[0-9-]{10}`

Your expression just checks that there is a substring of 10 digits or dashes in your string. Wrap it with **^..$** to specify that it should strictly fall between start and end of your string.

Comment: Thank you. It works! But for one case it doesn't, why is it so? matches(//ns123:birthDate, "^[T0-9-:]{24}$") Content is: 1938-08-09T00:00:00.000

Comment: Because: 1 - there is a dot in your content, 2 - there are 23 symbols. Your query should be: ^[T0-9-:\.]{23}$